# How can I set two values at a single command? Here I want to set Country name for Los Vegas and Alaska from a single sql command

Tags: mysql

```
select *from drcat;

+----+-------+-----+----------+------------+---------+
| id | name  | age | salary   | address    | Country |
+----+-------+-----+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 | ALICE |  27 | 84000.00 | Los Vegas  | 0       |
|  2 | BOB   |  30 | 90000.50 | California | 0       |
|  3 | SMITH |  28 | 88000.89 | New York   | USA     |
|  4 | DAVID |  30 | 78000.00 | Virginia   | 0       |
|  5 | PETER |  26 | 89321.00 | Singapore  | 0       |
|  6 | NOVAK |  28 | 96015.00 | Alaska     | 0       |
|  7 | HAL   |  32 | 74552.00 | New York   | USA     |
+----+-------+-----+----------+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE drcat SET Country='USA' WHERE address='California' 'Alaska';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Maybe you need a different [comparison operator or function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html). Check the MySQL docs to see if there's something you can use to match against multiple values.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an OR condition:

```
UPDATE drcat SET Country='USA' WHERE address='California' OR address='Alaska';
```

or you can use IN ([List of values]):

```
UPDATE drcat SET Country='USA' WHERE address IN ('California', 'Alaska');
```

Comment: i"m gald to help.